# How to get the replies over a message using Java Mail?

Tags: java, maven, email, jakarta-mail

How do i get the replies over a email message ?

The replais from the sender and also the replies sent from the recipients.

Also... Which one of these api is better to use?

```
"com.sun.mail » jakarta.mail"
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail
```

or

```
"jakarta.mail » jakarta.mail-api"
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api
```

Comment: You would get the replies by opening the Inbox, usually with IMAP these days. As to which API use, you would use the one that is most currently maintained and supportive of JavaMail - I don't know which is

Comment: Actually i already have a IMAP connection working, and it give me a Message[] when i get messages from Inbox.

But there isn't any property like getReplies() that could give me the replies over the main message, or any relation ID between the messages that could tell me which one is the main message and which are replies.

Comment: There's probably a way of doing it, maybe with headers, as that's precisely what is done with mailing lists such as [this](https://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/get_iplayer/2022-April/thread.html), which are, after all. done entirely with email by the client